# pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen keeps returning NoneType object

Tags: python, pyautogui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ne73.png)

As the screenshot I'd like to push '1','+' and '3' buttons,

but pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen keeps returning NoneType error.

I read some related questions and,

- have my calculator on the screen when code running like the link above
- cropped the button images in Paint after took a screenshot with built in function(pyautogui.screenshot('filename.png')

  `pyautogui.click(1472,211)
  x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\이원복\\티몬 
  \\크롤링\\패캠\\11번가\\1.png')
  pyautogui.click(x, y)
  TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

I use dual monitors. Screenshot I attached is the main monitor and I opened a code editor in the second monitor.

Could you tell me why it returns None?

Comment: try printing the result of it see what is printed, and also update you pyautogui, as in earlier versions it used to return `None` but now it raises `ImageNotFoundException`

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj how can I update pyautogui? I installed it "conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui" because pip install pyautogui returned "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 "

Comment: Is it possible that the `1.png` image is not yet displayed when you run `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()`? I have , in the past, put that function in a loop and it sometimes took a few tries to find the image.

Comment: Ok I just tried it myself, make sure your calculator is in the same background as it is transparent and also they are not in focus, as it will be lighter in colour if the app is in focus, so open the calculator and then take a screen shot, crop the image and then try with that.